# Colores en un Scatter Plot con Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Les cuento un poco de qué se trata mi problema, tengo una matriz muy grande 3000x16, como pueden imaginarse cada columna es 3000x1. Quiero hacer el diagrama dispersión de una de las columnas, llamada mos, contra otras 11, osea 11 diagramas de dispersión. Quiero que los puntos de cada diagrama de dispersión estén pintados según una tercera variable guardada en otra de las columnas, llamada distortions.
La columna distortions sigue la siguiente lógica: tiene cinco 1's, cinco 2's, ..., hasta cinco 24's y arranca de nuevo con cinco 1's, y sigue,... Como es una columna 3000x1, hace esto 25 veces.

```
distortions = [ 1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2 ... 24  24  24  24  24]
```

Así, a cada uno de los elementos de las otras columnas, le corresponde la distorsión que está en la misma posición, por ejemplo, a todos los elementos de la fila 7 le corresponde la distorsión 2. Quiero que esto se refleje en colores en el scatter plot, osea voy a necesitar 24 colores.

El siguiente código no está funcionando:

```
for metric in ['MSE', 'RMSE', 'PSNR', 'SNR', 'WSNR', 'UQI', 'PBVIF', 
'NQM', 'SSIM', 'MSSIM', 'Indice CQ(1,1)']:
    plt.scatter(value[metric], mos, c = distortions)  
    plt.title(metric + ' vs MOS')
    plt.ylabel('MOS')
    plt.xlabel(metric)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

(Nota: 'MSE', 'RMSE', ... son los nombres de las 11 columnas que quiero graficar contra la columna mos, están todas guardadas en un diccionario llamado value)

El parámetro que mete los colores es:

```
c = distortions
```

en la tercera línea, pero cuando ejecuto el Script hace gráficos con muy pocos colores, por lo que evidentemente está mal, ya que deberían ser 24 colores.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Lucía

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posiblemente esté 'repitiendo' colores al usar un mapa secuencial. En realidad el problema es que toma colores que son diferentes pero tan próximos que los vemos igual.  El mapa que estas usando por defecto es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver entre 1 y 5 (por ejemplo) las diferencias son practicamente inapreciables.

Para solucionar esto puedes [definir el mapa de color a usar](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) o crearte uno a medida para que acentuar las diferencias entre cada color.

Para definir tu propio mapa de color hay varias formas. A modo de ejemplo una de las formas más simple y manual que hay y es definiendo una lista con tus 24 colores a usar. El ejemplo está basado en tu código pero simplificado, solo graficamos una columna y los datos son generados aleatoriamente:

```
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

distortions = [n for n in np.arange(1, 25) for _ in np.arange(5)]*25

#Generamos valores aleatorio a modo de muestra
mos = [random() for _ in np.arange(3000)]
value = {'MSE':[random() for _ in np.arange(3000)]}

#lista con los 24 colores a usar
colors = ['black',    'silver',    'red',        'sienna',     'moccasin',          'gold',
          'orange',   'salmon',    'chartreuse', 'green',      'mediumspringgreen', 'lightseagreen',
          'darkcyan', 'royalblue', 'blue',       'blueviolet', 'purple',            'fuchsia',
          'pink',     'tan',       'olivedrab',  'tomato',     'yellow',            'turquoise']

for metric in ['MSE', 'RMSE', 'PSNR', 'SNR', 'WSNR', 'UQI', 'PBVIF', 
'NQM', 'SSIM', 'MSSIM', 'Indice CQ(1,1)']:
    plt.scatter(value[metric], mos, c = distortions, cmap=ListedColormap(colors))  
    plt.title(metric + ' vs MOS')
    plt.ylabel('MOS')
    plt.xlabel(metric)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.tight_layout()

    #Mostrar la barra de colores con cada etiqueta de distortions y su color asociado
    loc = np.linspace(min(distortions) -0.5 , max(distortions) -0.5,  max(distortions)+1 )
    cb = plt.colorbar(spacing='proportional',ticks=loc)
    cb.set_ticklabels(np.arange(min(distortions), max(distortions)+1))
    cb.set_label('Distortions')

    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**P.D:** por si a alguien le interesa, un lista extensa con los nombres de los colores y su valor rgb se puede ver en la siguiente pregunta del sitio en Inglés:

[Named colors in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22408237/7131499)

Comment: Excelente! Y me re sirve la barra de colores al lado también!! pero que tal si en vez de poner los nombres de los colores quiero poner el nombre de la distorsión que corresponde a dicho color?

Comment: @Lucy_in_the_sky_with_diamonds he editando la respuesta modificando el código y mostrando la grafica generada para lo que quieres. Ahora la barra de colores muestra cada valor de `distortions` asociado. Saludos.

Comment: Ok, bastante mejor, pero si en vez del número de distorsión quisiera un string con el nombre de dicha distorsión?

Comment: @Lucy_in_the_sky_with_diamonds pasale a `cb.set_ticklabels` la lista con los 24 nombres ordenados corrrectamente (el primer nombre es el que se corresponde con el 1 en `distortions`, el segundo con el 2, etc) en vez de la lista que se le pasa ahora (que son los numeros de 1 a 24 ) simplemente.

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias!